Entity framework, views and error 6002 does not have a primary key
I'm getting "Error 6002: The table/view 'xxx' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view" when I add a view to the model.
Previously I've edited the view in the diagram and checked the 'Entity Key' on an appropriate column, which has resolved the issue.
But this time around I'm continuing to get the warnings and I am, presumably in consequence, unable to add any further tables or stored procs to the model.
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and just updated to the current release 17.9.6 in case that brought a solution. But the problem remains.

The warning messages weren't the cause of the problem.
My resolution for this one was adding TrustServerCertificate=True to the connect string in web.config.
